# In 3.0.0 unlike ODatabaseDocumentTx , OrientDB constructor throwing exception for in memory DB

Tags: orientdb

**Summary**

I am using OrientDB 3.0.0 and I'm trying to avoid deprecated APIs like ODatabaseDocumentTx. However, when I replace it with com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDB ; for the same configs that otherwise work fine it blows up.

Details below...

**Configuration**

```
    odb.url=memory:neurosys_orientdb_odb
    odb.username=admin
    odb.password=admin
    odb.maxPartitionSize=2
    odb.maxPoolSize=10
```

**Spring Configs using ODatabaseDocumentTx that works**

```
    <bean id="dataSourceOdb" class="com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx" init-method="create">
        <constructor-arg value = "${odb.url}"/>     
</bean>

<bean id="connectionPoolDataSourceOdb" class="com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool">
    <constructor-arg value = "${odb.url}" index="0"/>
    <constructor-arg value = "${odb.username}" index="1"/>
    <constructor-arg value = "${odb.password}" index="2"/>
    <constructor-arg value = "${odb.maxPartitionSize}" index="3"/>
    <constructor-arg value = "${odb.maxPoolSize}" index="4"/>       
</bean>
```

Spring Configs using com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDB that does **not** work

Simply replacing the  `dataSourceOdb` bean.

```
<bean id="dataSourceOdbNew" class="com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDB">  
<constructor-arg value = "${odb.url}"/>
    <constructor-arg value = "${odb.username}" />
    <constructor-arg value = "${odb.password}" />       
<constructor-arg><null /></constructor-arg>
```

**Exception thrown**

> com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Cannot open database 'neurosys_orientdb_odb'
>   at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBEmbedded.open(OrientDBEmbedded.java:140)
>   at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.open(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:908)
>   at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool$DatabaseDocumentTxPooled.internalOpen(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:441)
>   at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.openDatabase(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:306)
>   at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OPartitionedDatabasePool.acquire(OPartitionedDatabasePool.java:261)
>   ...
>   at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Cannot open the storage 'neurosys_orientdb_odb' because it does not exist in path: D:\orientdb./neurosys_orientdb_odb
>   at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.open(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:267)
>   at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.OrientDBEmbedded.open(OrientDBEmbedded.java:131)
>   ... 34 more

**Possible cause**
It looks like the path is getting messed up by assuming a Unix convention path even for an in memory DB. I am on Windows but I don't see why that matters for an in-memory DB. Plus it works with the deprecated API so I assume this is a bug. If not, please let me know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by making a distinction between `url` and `database` and not to include the database in the url.

Then to make things 1 step IOC friendly; wrote a factory that returns `pool`

```
        OrientDB odb = new OrientDB(url, OrientDBConfig.defaultConfig());
    odb.createIfNotExists(database, odbType==null?ODatabaseType.MEMORY:odbType);    

    OrientDBConfig config = OrientDBConfig.builder().build(); //... configBuilder.addConfig(OGlobalConfiguration key, value);
    ODatabasePool pool = new ODatabasePool(odb, database, username, password, config);
```

Where the configurations are now:
(orientdb & see https://orientdb.com/docs/2.1.x/Configuration.html)

```
odb.url=memory:
odb.database=neurosys_orientdb_odb
odb.username=admin
odb.password=admin
odb.pool.min=1
odb.pool.max=5
```

Note: The above configs are custom to the app but map to a `OGlobalConfiguration` constant

Answer (score 0):

A database using memory storage is designated by a URL of the form memory:, for example memory:test. A hierarchical path is allowed, for example memory:subdir/test.
The problem seems that the path for the DB doesn't exists.

```
D:\orientdb./neurosys_orientdb_odb
```

Is correct that you have a`.` in your path?

If it's not try to use `\` instead of `/` and delete the `.` in the path.

Let me know if this resolve your problem.

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: The './' is added by orientDB. In my code (configs), its simply just plain ol `odb.url=memory:neurosys_orientdb_odb`. I also read up [ODB 3 Docs > Internals > Memory Storage](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/internals/Memory-storage.html) but dont understand what significance a path for memory even has as its all going into volatile memory (same destination irrsepective of path)